# How to make Eclipse serve up a default servlet url?

Tags: java, servlets

I have this line in my servlet code (in a dynamic web project):

```
@WebServlet("/login")
```

But when I right-click on the project, run-as, run on server, it serves up

```
http://localhost:8090/LoginServletApp/
```

which results in a 404. I have to manually change the url to

```
http://localhost:8090/LoginServletApp/login
```

How can I make this url (i.e. ending in "/login") be served up by default? I've done some looking around, and a file called web.xml is mentioned, which can be created on a per-project basis, but this seems to apply to physical files; I asked eclipse to generate a deployment descriptor and it created this file for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">
  <display-name>LoginServletApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Thank you in advance, and apologies if this has been asked before (it probably has, but I can't find it or a solution).

Edit: I added the line below to the web.xml file but as expected it didn't work:

```
<welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the entry in welcome-file-list , the container looks for the file in the order. So if you add login to the list as first, it would served up first and you will not get 404.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login</welcome-file>
    ..
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Hi, that works, thanks very much. I had to restart the server (w/o restarting it didn't work for some reason) but now it's working. Simple as that. Thanks.